# Configuring openCV with Qt in windows

Tags: qt, opencv

I have a project which uses openCV. I am trying to set up openCV library to use in my Qt application.

For my Qt installation I installed Visual Studio and am using its compiler and CDS debugger. After doing all this when I am going through the documentation I am seeing that MinGW is used to configure openCV and Qt (https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows)

But in most cases we will be using VS, so how can someone configure openCV with Qt if using Visual Studio compilers.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install the Visual Studio plugin - http://doc.qt.io/qtvstools/index.html

You then need to make sure you have built both OpenCV & Qt for whatever compiler you are using. VS2017 for example, I don't think the default binaries come with the Qt option. There is an installation guide here - https://wiki.qt.io/OpenCV_with_Qt

Comment: So the best way is if I install using the pre-built libraries and then setting the environment path right?

Comment: I have followed the following guidance to install QT with VS debuggers and compilers : https://forum.qt.io/topic/60713/setting-visual-studio-2015-debugger/6. Do I need the visual studio plugin even then?

Comment: You need the VS plugin for Qt as it manages all the project files for you. Otherwise you would need to run qmake (or moc I can't remember which) every time you do a build.

Comment: This is because of using openCV in the project or for just QT project also will it be required?

Comment: Qt projects, OpenCV can just be included as include directories and libs

Comment: But I tried the default Qt widget program and it was building and running without any tool. Any reason why it didn't need?

Comment: I think as you get more complicated projects/multiple UI files etc. I'm not sure though. - Worth reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894097/how-do-i-use-qt-in-my-visual-studio-2015-projects

Comment: This link has said how to use : http://blog.sensoviz.com/startopencv
Will it work?

Comment: This will https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537226/setting-up-opencv-3-1-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: I am using Qt Creator and not Visual Studio to run the program